# Postgres catch exception when refcursor is not opened

Tags: postgresql

I have created a procedure with INOUT refcursor parameter.

```
create or replace procedure test_rc(inout ref_cur refcursor)
as
$$
begin
if 1 = 2 then
open ref_cur for select 'one';
end if;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

If the control doesn't reach the '`OPEN refcursor.........`' statement during procedure execution, I always get the below error.

> ERROR:  cursor "r" does not exist SQL state: 34000

How can I catch this in an exception block to avoid getting error and return a NULL refcursor output instead? (Just like in Oracle PL/SQL).

I have tried using `WHEN sqlstate '34000'` in `exception` block but it did not catch this exception.

Comment: This procedure can't throw that exception. The caller could, if it tried to use a cursor that was never opened, but that's like reading a variable that was never initialized. Just don't do that, it's a bug.

Comment: Also, why do you use a procedure and a `refcursor` rather than doing the natural thing: a function that returns `SETOF text`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, i have posted a simpler version of the procedure. The actual procedure returns a query with multiple columns and has multiple tables joined.

Comment: That wouldn't speak against using a function, would it?